# SQLite DB Returning Always String Zero

Tags: android, sqlite

I am sending some String parameters to database class. I am debugging there and i am watching my all parameters going there correctly. But when i read database some columns always returning String zero "0". I am working three hours and i can not find a solution. I am sharing my codes here. Waiting your advise thank you.

My Database Class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String Create_Table = "CREATE TABLE " + YAYIN_TABLE + "("
            + GONDERI_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + TOPLAM_FIYAT + " TEXT,"
            + GONDERI_ZAMAN + " TEXT,"
            + KOMBIN + " TEXT,"
            + LIKE + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(Create_Table);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //implemented Method
}

public void YeniGonderi(String topFiyat,String gonderiZaman,String filename) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TOPLAM_FIYAT,topFiyat);
    values.put(GONDERI_ZAMAN,gonderiZaman);
    values.put(KOMBIN,filename);
    db.insert(YAYIN_TABLE,null,values);
    db.close();
}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> Yayinlar(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + YAYIN_TABLE;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SelectQuery,null);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> yayinlar = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            for (int i = 0;i<cursor.getColumnCount();i++) {
                map.put(cursor.getColumnName(i),String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(i)));
            }
            yayinlar.add(map);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return yayinlar;
}
```

My Value Send Codes (Everythings fine here. I am debugging and watching all variables.)

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
String now = df.format(new Date());
db = new DBase(getContext());
db.YeniGonderi(topfs,now,"TEST");
```

ListView getView Method

```
    HashMap<String,String> map = arayList.get(position);

    Gonderi gonderi = new Gonderi(map.get(GONDERI_ID),map.get(TOPLAM_FIYAT),map.get(LIKE),map.get(GONDERI_ZAMAN),map.get(KOMBIN));
```

GONDERI_ZAMAN and KOMBIN returning always String Zero. But TOPLAM_FIYAT returning normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in below line:

```
map.put(cursor.getColumnName(i),String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(i)));
```

And you are using unnecessary for loop inside do while loop. You are not specifying column name to get the value for map.

Try this:

```
if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
          do {
               HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
               map.put(cursor.getColumnName(i),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TOPLAM_FIYAT")));
               yayinlar.add(map);
          }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you're trying to store each row of the cursor in a `List`, which elements are `HashMap`s that are going to contain the name of the column as key and the column value as the map value. If you're actually trying to do this, then the `while` and `for` loops inside `Yayinlar()` are correct.

The issue is that you're declaring the columns as `TEXT` , and you're trying to fetch them with `cursor.getInt(i)`. Try changing:

`map.put(cursor.getColumnName(i),String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(i)));`

for:

`map.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));`